# Build a react library using typescript and debug it in another project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I am building a react library using typescript, my project structure is:

```
dist/
example/simple
src/
...config files
```

The folder `simple` is created using `create-react-app`. I have already done `npm link` process in the `simple` folder linking `my-lib` to the outter project. But when i using `import {...} from 'my-lib'` from `simple`, an error message shows:

```
D:/codes/my-lib-folder/dist/my-lib.js 
Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: 'D:\codes\my-lib-folder\node_modules\React\react'.
```

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./dist/",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es5",
  "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
      "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

My webpack config is:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "my-lib.js",
    library: "myLib",
    libraryTarget: "umd"
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    "react": "React"
  },
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV ? process.env.NODE_ENV : "development"
};
```

Comment: never post image, post code. Easy to debug and reproduce.

Comment: already changed to codes